# Devexpress Barcode QRCode

Tags: devexpress, barcode

I have a problem about Devexpress Barcode. This value for example : 20-030-01-01 (00). Code128 generates the barcode but QRCode does NOT. The problem is that QRCode shows the parentheses as an invalid character.

Do you have any experience for that?

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change barcode control symbology **compaction mode** setting to **Byte**